# Pervasive PSQL v11 - Automate Export Tables to CSV Files?

Tags: sql-server, csv, 32bit-64bit, pervasive

I am trying to find any free method possible to automate export of Pervasive PSQL tables to CSV files. I can do manual exports from the GUI of the application running on PSQL (`Sage 50` in this case). But we need to be able to set up a scheduled task to export files on a regular basis. From something like a batch file, for instance.

I've been scouring the internet all day but have yet to find any definite answers aside from the usual spam of small software companies sharing their external tools which usually have outrageous price tags. Is there really no command that can be run from a Windows Batch File to query PSQL directly to retrieve data? Any other solution you would recommend?

If nothing else, I have 32-bit ODBC connections that could be accessed from some other database system to connect and export the data that way. However, the 64-bit ODBC driver is missing for some reason (from what I've read, there SHOULD be one for PSQL v11+, but it isn't there?). The SQL Server my software is running on is 64-bit... otherwise I would just get a direct connection (which is what I was trying to do all day yesterday).

At the end of the day, all I really need is a straightforward and low-overhead way to import data from 32-bit `Progressive PSQL v11` to 64-bit `SQL Server 2016 Express`. Any suggestions or leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured a working ODBC System DSN to connect to the Pervasive.SQL DB? Note that when you are creating a 32 bit DSN on a 64 bit machine, you should use the 32 bit ODBC app - usually *C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\odbc32.exe*

Comment: @LaughingVergil yes. Created from SYSWOW64 directory. The System32 directory ODBC config app (64-bit) does not have any Pervasive driver listed.

Comment: Do you have a low-overhead method you would recommend to use the 32-bit ODBC connection for Pervasive? Unfortunately, the SQL Server that we are using on the same machine is 64-bit.

Comment: If you've got PSQL v11, you should have access to a 64 bit ODBC driver.  You might have to download the 64 bit client from Pervasive's web site (http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv11.aspx) but that should get you a 64 bit ODBC driver.  Some applications that use the Pervasive engine don't include the full client.  THe 64 bit client can be installed at the same time as the 32 bit client.

Comment: I tried installing both the 32-bit Server and the 64-bit client on my laptop as a test, but I see no ODBC drivers added.

Comment: I'm wasting too much time on this, and I can't afford to risk messing up anything on the customer's production database, so I'm just installing an old version of SQL Server Express 32-bit so I can connect to the 32-bit driver. Thanks anyway.